# How to handle interviews for a requirement, on which I don't have hands-on experience but have learnt and interested to work upon?

Tags: software-industry, interviewing, skills

I am attending an interview with a requirement on some technology which I haven't worked upon but I have read and learnt this technology. I am interested to work on this technology. How would I put this forward to the interviewer?

Comment: At least in these parts of the world, passing the initial screening and getting to an actual interview means that they already accepted your technical skill level. The interview is for testing if your personality is a fit for the company.

Comment: Tell in application about your excitement on the topic. A truly motivated application might outperform experience. I think  its very rare though.

Comment: edited: the opening is for a software developer

Comment: It really does not matter what the position is.  You approach it the same.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your approach depends on if this actually a requirement for the job, from the hiring company's perspective.

If this isn't a hard requirement, you could say "I haven't yet worked with that particular technology, but I have read and learned about it. I am interested to work on this technology."

Then, you could go on to tell them what you have learned in your reading, and how it relates to the position you are trying to fill. If you have used this technology on your own, talk about that too.

If this is a real requirement for the company, you may simply not fit their needs. Not every company is in a position to allow their new hire to learn important technology on the job.

But sometimes what is expressed as a requirement, is really just a nice-to-have. Your other skills and attributes may make up for your lack of knowledge in this area.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First of all my answer is solely directed towards the requirement being a programming language, certain API or a development framework (anything programming related actually except things like SCRUM).

For such occasions have a [github](https://github.com/) account where you keep the source of little applications that you've made in the course of familiarizing yourself with a certain technology. This is the most transparent approach imho. Include the github link in your CV but for it to make a good impression rather than bad you'll have to keep it up to date... Display it as "my personal projects repository" so that the idea behind it is not explicitly showing off or proving a skill but simply tracking the development of your passion in your free time. Even though the committed code might be a copy/pasted from a tutorial or somewhere else if you provide reasonable log entries for example 5 commits within a week that would indicate development rather than hollow approval seeking.

Yes, I know that you describe a situation where you've only theoretically been introduced to the matter but let's be honest here - in programming you don't really know much about a thing until you've put it to actual use.

Comment: Is it okay to put personal projects in the resume? If yes where exactly it should be mentioned- I mean at the beginnnig/end of projects done? Do they consider personal projects as experience?

Comment: Ofcourse. Personal projects can win you a position. Depends on what CV template you are using (if any). For the given examples on the europass [page](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae/examples) (United Kingdom ones) I think it wouldn't be really appropriate placing it in "WORK EXPERIENCE" since you would have to bind every project with a date/duration. I find it better for such things to be listed either in ANNEXES section (if you provide any documentation bundled with the projects) or ADDITIONAL INFORMATION section (if you provide a github repository link).

Comment: Personal projects can help you when applying BUT only in certain situations. You wouldn't be taken seriously if you keep attaching that drawing app you did in college when you are applying for a Senior position - developer, engineer or even architect. But for an entry level position taking in account that you don't have any professional experience with the required technology, you need every little bit of evidential material relating your experience with that certain technology. But remember - never put anything in your CV that you can't prove in the live interview.

Answer (score 0):

If this company has anyone who knows what they're doing, they'll have you code some sample problems in this language (I'm shocked at the number of hiring situations that don't have candidates demonstrate they can perform the actual job.).

Be honest about your skill level and the fact you have not used it on the job. Another approach is to show how you've been able to learn new technologies before. There are some languages I've learned through self-study, so I see no reason why I couldn't learn others.